# Neptune Gremlin - how to write group by where count > 2

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

How can I achieve same effect as SQL in gremlin

`select A.id from A group by A.id having count(A.id)>2`

a further question would be, can I return all A's properties rather than just id?

e.g. below query return multiple V, with some V's Id duplicated. I only want to get those duplicated V returned, exclude the count()==1

`g.V().hasLabel('A').as('Root').until(__.hasId('abc','xyz')).repeat(__.outE('A-B','A-C').inV()).select('Root').valueMap(true).toList()`

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. Is A meant to represent a vertex in the graph? I ask as all ID values must be unique so counting as you show above does not quite make sense. To get all the properties there are steps such as values() and valueMap()

Answer (score 1):

There are some unclear things in your question.

ID is a unique value, I assume you meant a different property or a vertex that associated with a group multiple times.

For property:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Group').
  has('name', within('A', 'B')).out('in').
  group().by('prop1').by().unfold().
    select(values).
  where(count(local).is(gt(1))).unfold().
  valueMap(true)
```

For the multi-edge:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Group').
  has('name', within('C')).out('in').
  groupCount().by().unfold().
  where(select(values).
    is(gt(1))).select(keys).
  valueMap(true)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/9k